# How do I validate a particular field to be updated

Tags: java

There is a user which has certian clients under it . Each client has its certains details and unique UserName. I have given one option through which user can change or update its client details.

```
public String updateClientDetials()
{
    AccountService accountService = new AccountService();
    UserServiceAction userServiceAction = new UserServiceAction();
    Userr user = ( (OptionsUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUserr();
    user =  Userr.findUserr(user.getId());
    if(userServiceAction.isClientValid(user,uname,lastname,tandc).equals("valid")){
    Account account = accountService.getClientDetails(Long.parseLong(updateClientId));
    account.setUserName(uname);
    account.setLastName(lastname);
    account.setExpectedProfitPPA(userServiceAction.convertToDouble(eppa,new Double(100)));
    account.setMaxLossPPA(userServiceAction.convertToDouble(mlppa,new Double(80)));     
    }

}
```

Now while updating any client details I have to make sure that userName should not be same,that I am doing by caliiing" clientAlreadyExits()"

But at the same time time if I just update lastName then also its checking for the userName and shows that userName already exit. 
How do I validate a particular field to be updated ?

```
public String isClientValid(Userr user,String uname,String lastName,String tandc){
    System.out.println("Entering into isClientValid() of UserServiceAction ");
    if(uname.isEmpty()){
        return "Enter valid First Name";
    }else if(clientAlreadyExist(user,uname)){
        return "uname ID already exists";
    }
    else if(lastName.isEmpty()){
        return "Enter valid Last Name";
    }
    else if(tandc == null || tandc.isEmpty()){
        return "Kindly agree to the Terms and Conditions";
    }
    else if(("false").equals(tandc)) {
        return "Kindly agree to the Terms and Conditions";
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("Exiting from isClientValid() of UserServiceAction ");
    return "valid";
    }

}
```

Comment: if combining all validations into one method is the problem then create multiple methods to accomplish the task.  Perhaps one to validate the input fields and another to validate the username on the back-end.  Then I would expect there to be at least 2 calls to validate the update instead of just calling `isClientValid()` at the end.

Comment: @zec Okay I did it .